# When does walletnotify event occur on bitcoind

Tags: events, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have configured the `walletnotify` and the `blocknotify` event on the bitcoin daemon based on the documentation from  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin, to know any changes to my wallet. Only the `blocknotify` is executed and the `walletnotify` is never executed. Can someone advice on what event on the wallet will trigger the walletnotify event?

**Bitcoin daemon version currently running on:  0.8.1**

**bitcoin.conf**

`rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=bitcoinrpc1
server=1
testnet=1
walletnotify=/home/dev/test_log/log.sh %s
blocknotify=/home/dev/test_log/log.sh %s`

Answer (score 3):

[Walletnotify](https://bitcointa.lk/threads/how-to-use-walletnotify-and-blocknotify.253062/) will get triggered when:

- First receiving a payment
- First conformation on the payment
- You send a payment

Answer (score 2):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

> -walletnotify=    Execute command when a wallet transaction changes (%s in cmd is replaced by TxID)

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/1974

> Exactly like -blocknotify, except that it gives the TxID of transactions that hit the wallet.
>
> Note that this is NOT a payment notification. It will trigger on outgoing transactions too, and can trigger multiple times on the same transaction.

Comment: can we get it to notify on other important events, like bitcoind daemon unexpectedly shutting down?